# How to test a function that uses the same path for finding and creating files so it'll create in a temporary dir?

Tags: python, pytest, temporary-files

I want to write a test for a function using Pytest. The function gets an id by which it finds the path to a video file, and then creates another folder in the video's folder (to put some new files in it). Here is the function:

```
def foo(id):
    root_dir = find_local_dir(id) # finds the path to the video file 
    video_file = root_dir / 'video.mp4'
    out_dir = root_dir / 'foo'
    out_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

I have a video in the `tests` directory which I would like to use for testing, and I use `monkeypatch` to prevent the function from looking for the video according to the id. But I don't know how to make it get the video in `tests` and create the new folder in a tmp, **without changing** `foo`.

I tried to copy the video from `tests` to `tmp_path` but that doesn't work:

```
def test_foo(tmp_path, monkeypatch):
    id = '1234'

    mock = MagicMock()
    mock.return_value = tmp_path
    monkeypatch.setattr(pipeline, 'find_local_dir', mock)
    
    copy2('coffee.mp4', tmp_path / 'video.mp4')

    var = pipeline.foo(id)
```

And the error I had was `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

I guess the copying didn't work? (I'm a bit new to Pytest so I don't know if that's even possible.)

I'll be happy with any other way to solve this without changing `foo`.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
def find_local_dir(id):
    local_dir = Path(f'/tmp/{id}')
    local_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    return local_dir
```

Comment: What does `find_local_dir` return? A raw string? Or something else? Could you share its implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a video in the tests directory which I would like to use for testing

So I assume you already have a `tests` directory which we can use as our temporary directory for testing. Now, all that we need to control is the output of `find_local_dir()` to point to the `tests` directory because

- It is where the `video.mp4` is located
- It is where the directory `foo` would be created

**File tree**

```
$ tree 
.
├── pipeline.py
└── tests
    ├── coffee.mp4
    └── test_pipeline.py
```

**pipeline.py**

```
from pathlib import Path


def find_local_dir(id):
    local_dir = Path(f'/tmp/{id}')
    local_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    return local_dir


def foo(id):
    root_dir = find_local_dir(id) # finds the path to the video file 
    video_file = root_dir / 'video.mp4'
    out_dir = root_dir / 'foo'
    out_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    # Let's add a print to see the location of the video file
    print(f"{video_file=}")
```

**test_pipeline.py**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy2, rmtree
import time
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import pytest

import pipeline


@pytest.fixture
def tmp_path(mocker):
    local_dir = Path(f'./tests/tmp')
    local_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    yield local_dir

    # Optionally, delete the temporary directory used for testing
    rmtree(local_dir)


def test_foo(tmp_path, monkeypatch):
    id = '1234'

    mock = MagicMock()
    mock.return_value = tmp_path
    monkeypatch.setattr(pipeline, 'find_local_dir', mock)

    copy2('./tests/coffee.mp4', tmp_path / 'video.mp4')

    pipeline.foo(id)

    # Remove this line. It is just here so that we can see the files before deletion.
    time.sleep(10)
```

Running the test

```
$ pytest -q -rP
                                                                                                            
================================================================================================= PASSES ==================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_foo _________________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
video_file=PosixPath('tests/tmp/video.mp4')
1 passed in 0.05s
```

File tree while the test is ongoing

```
$ tree
.
├── pipeline.py
└── tests
    ├── coffee.mp4
    ├── test_pipeline.py
    └── tmp
        ├── foo
        └── video.mp4
```

File tree after the test finished

```
$ tree
.
├── pipeline.py
└── tests
    ├── coffee.mp4
    └── test_pipeline.py
```

As you can see, the location of the video file is correct at `tests/tmp/video.mp4`. The new directory was also correctly created at `tests/tmp/foo`. Then at the end of the test, the temporary `tests/tmp/` was deleted.

Comment: Thanks!  just to clarify, 1. test_pipeline.py is also in `tests`. 2. Will the directory 'foo' be deleted when the test finishes?

Comment: I updated the answer. I moved the test_pipeline.py inside tests. Then for ease of testing, all temporary files will be in `tests/tmp` which would then be deleted at the end of the test (without deleting any pre-existing test files). Can you check if this suits your needs?

Comment: Sorry for the time, it worked!! but does defining `tmp_path` on my own like you showed will change `tmp_path` for other tests as well?

Comment: It will not automatically reflect on the other tests unless you patched explicitly `monkeypatch.setattr(pipeline, 'find_local_dir', mock)` where `mock` contains the `tmp_path`. If you want it to automatically reflect, you might be interested in putting it inside a pytest fixture with the flag `autouse=True`.